# Which versions of Windows support FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY?

Tags: windows, winapi

There is not much information about `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior).

I need to know which versions of Windows support it, in particular does XP support it?

Comment: If I make downvote, I will downvote, because from docs is clearly known, which attributes are supported.

Comment: @user2120666 Is it? I couldn't find any definitive answer. Perhaps you could post a link, or add the relevant text as an answer.

Comment: For example: FILE_FLAG_SESSION_AWARE - Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2003:  This flag is not supported before Windows Server 2012. Other attributes are supported from Minimum supported client/server. This is working for other functions/structs in MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file attribute constants are bitmasks:

https://serverfault.com/a/517023

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Given that FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY is a fairly low value (256) and attributes such as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA, which has a higher value 131072 (0x20000) are explictly supported on XP, it seems reasonable to expect that FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY was also supported.

Comment: The problem with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY is that there is no real way to check if the OS honors it. If the file is big enough to notice the difference, you might attribute it to swapping.

Answer (score 5):

The page you referenced says the function is supported since Windows XP (for desktop).  In the remarks section, there are clear notes when the behavior differs from one version to another.  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY is not mentioned in any of those sections, so you should be able to safely assume that FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY works as described back to Windows XP.

I've also used it in programs on Windows XP without issue.

Comment: @eryksun: Throughout the MSDN reference documentation, the minimum supported client and server fields tell you at what point in the evolution of WinAPI, the functionality became available.  This is generally at the API (function/structure) level.  Sometimes, an existing API is extended with new flags, so you have to read all the remarks to be sure.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The "minimum supported" fields in the documentation mean supported by the Windows SDK (formerly known as the Platform SDK), which is decoupled from tech support.  The current SDK doesn't support targeting Windows NT 3.1.  The April deadline on XP is primarily about security updates and maybe activation.  It's not really about tech support.  Whether the next version of the SDK cuts off Windows XP remains to be seen.  Given how the Visual Studio team put XP support back in due to developer demand, I'd be surprised if they yank it right away.